# Mysql Query to fetch records

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla1.5

I have a table structure which looks like as follows[image]

In the above table I need the `team_id` for which `win+runs_scored` is *maximum*.

I know that task can be accomplished by PHP code but if there is any query possible for this then it would be easier for me and also main thing is that in real table contains more then *15000 rows* so please if some can can provide me a better solution then it would be great

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.team_id 
from YourTable t
order by t.win + t.run_scored desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(t.win + t.run_scored) ,t.team_id 
from YourTable t
group by t.team_id 
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  teamid FROM 
(  
SELECT max(win+run_scored),teamid FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY teamid 
ORDER BY max(win+run_scored) desc
)
WHERE rownum <= 1
```